# How to make .nuget\NuGet.Config file attached to VS solution to be not ignored?

Tags: nuget

I've created new solution in Visual Studio, enable nuget package restore and got in soluition root `.nuget` folder which contains the following files needed to make package restore work: `NuGet.exe`, `NuGet.config`, `NuGet.targets`.

But I can't make nuget(as Nuget Visual Studio add-in and `\.nuget\NuGet.exe` as well) read setting from `.\nuget\NuGet.config` file - settings are still read from default `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.config`.

**What have I tried.**
I've tried to look where the path to `NuGet.config` is specified and haven't found anything like that, and `nuget.exe install` command that runs during build doesn't have any parameter saying like "take this nuget.config file".

Also I've removed `\.nuget\NuGet.config` and everything works - packages are restored during Visual Studio build and CI one.

**Question.**
I've got an impression that `\.nuget\NuGet.config` isn't used at all.

So essentially the question is:  How to make `.nuget\NuGet.Config` file to be not ignored?
What am I doing wrong and how to do it write?

Thanks and have a nice %time_of_day% :)

Disclaimer
*Everything that I've mentioned above is not a problem/issue - current nuget behavior is completely acceptable for me - I'm asking just because I'm curious and confused at the same time*

Answer (score 16):

I haven't tried this personally, but here is what the [official Nuget 2.1 release notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1) say:

> NuGet.config files are searched for in the following order:
>
> 1. .nuget\nuget.config
> 2. Recursive walk from project folder to root
> 3. Global nuget.config (%appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config)
>
> The configurations are than applied in the reverse order, meaning that
>   based on the above ordering, the global nuget.config would be applied
>   first, followed by the discovered nuget.config files from root to
>   project folder, followed by .nuget

If this doesn't help I'd suggest you write more specifically what you're trying to achieve and which config settings you're changing - knowing more details about the problem may clarify the situation.

Comment: IN Visual Studio 2015, I tried .nuget\nuget.config and .\nuget.config - without success. The configuration file is ignored.

Comment: Global nuget.config where is in ubuntu?

Comment: Tip for all that try this: You need to restart Visual Studio after the file was added/changed

Answer (score 2):

Did you point the config file that you want to use as ?

In nuget [page](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) example;

```
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile c:\my.config
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile .\myApp\NuGet.Config
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile %ProgramData%\NuGet\Config\VisualStudio\14.0\NuGet.Config
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile %ProgramData%\NuGet\NuGetDefaults.Config
```

Comment: I can't specify the config file when building with studio. In the package manager console, nuget is not known as command, nor is it known in the command window.

Comment: @Slesa to go C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 2015 location and click Ctrl+RightClick select "Open Command Prompt Here". Then you'll use nuget exe to configurate

Comment: But then it would work only on my machine (if so). The buildserver would not work.

Comment: Are you going to build it on other PC or on TFS ?

Comment: It was on PC. The problem was obiously, that I had to restart VStudio to see the changes. Very strange.